# PHP Paypal API not working

Tags: php, paypal

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this code.

I'm not getting complete from paypal.

Once i paied i should be getting to this `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)` but i'm not.

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$mode = $paymod_data['MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_TESTMODE'];

if ($mode == 'test')
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}
else
{
    $fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
}

if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
     die ("Error");
}
else 
{   
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            processing ( $_POST );      
        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {
        }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: what are you getting returned?

Comment: when i ask paypal to send me information i can see all the information i'm getting back.

Comment: but when i ask to send what is value for strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") i get -1 thats it.

Comment: paypal is send the information but for some reason i can't process it.

Comment: Try `print_r($res)` after you assign this variable, so you can see what _is_ coming back.

Comment: yes i can see everything which is coming back from paypal.

Comment: This is what i'm getting back with print_r "1"

Comment: This is what i'm getting back. s:19:\"Content-Length: 0
\";

s:19:\"Connection: close
\";

s:15:\"Server: BigIP
\";

s:20:\"HTTP/1.0 302 Found
\";

s:2:\"
\";

s:42:\"Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
\";

Comment: use curl, and don't bother with low level sockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things are wrong with your code ... you don't have to use CURL for it too work

1. Paypall runs on https and not http
2. To use https with fsockopen you need to start with ssl://

   ```
       $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
       foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
       {
           $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
           $req .= "&$key=$value";
       }
       $header = "" ;
       $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
       $mode = "test";
       $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
       if (!$fp)
       {
           // HTTP ERROR
            die ("Error");
       }
       else 
       {   
           fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
           $res = ""  ;
           while (!feof($fp))
           {
               $res .= fgets ($fp, 1024) ."\n";

           }
           fclose ($fp);

           echo "<pre>" ;
           echo $res ;
       }
   ```

working version

```
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                // check the payment_status is Completed
                // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                // process payment
            }
            else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                // log for manual investigation
            }
        }
```

Output

```
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK

        Date: Thu, 22 Mar 2012 22:29:27 GMT

        Server: Apache

        X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

        Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=laL_1TsCkmAu0I-qPtcD7bI-NtAFnmmf5vK3gjnt0FNUFLhrF50wv9851dshc41cwX1vHP3ZnbZQtv8w1TX8zBbshkoktJrD3JOE7FhzbSTRfUD7wuKT2247G9Ktz0pQv3Pnb0%7cUz1hwgrtOfBwB4QUN_sOl-xjUAxIgPAln4rJ0NF6J0xDeav4ApvI_FdaX-6IDCmKCcK59m%7cbBVb109UB7lSNC7p_sKz2KLrSiHT_JhBpu6_CtqDTSUFZhXYvLNzVFJEp3jTcj02IJMwg0%7c1332455367; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

        Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sun, 20-Mar-2022 22:29:27 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

        Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

        Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 17-Mar-2032 22:29:27 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

        Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1332455367151823; path=/; expires=Sat, 15-Mar-42 22:29:27 GMT

        Connection: close

        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: This worked. why did the other didn't work. its same this. just without https